# Getting empty value of column in database table, used belongsTo() method - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get value of table column I used several things and none of them work, I'm always getting an empty value.

**Here's my Code:**

**Models**

```
1- CourseGroup Model
class CourseGroup extends Model
{
     // Table Name
     protected $table = 'course_groups';
     // Primary Key
     public $primaryKey = 'id';
     // Timestamps
     public $timestamps = true;
}


2- Course Model
class Course extends Model
{
    // Table Name
    protected $table = 'courses';
    // Primary Key
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    // Timestamps
    public $timestamps = true;


    public function department()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Department::class);
    }

    public function courseGroup()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(CourseGroup::class);
    }

    public function courseOrder()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(CourseOrder::class);
    }

}
```

**Tables**

Table `courses`

```
#   Name                Type        
1   id                 bigint(20)
2   department_id      bigint(20)   
3   course_group       bigint(20)
4   course_order       bigint(20)
5   course_name        varchar(255)
6   course_number      bigint(20)
7   hours              int(11)
8   created_at         timestamp
9   updated_at         timestamp
```

Table `course_groups`

```
#   Name                 Type
1   id                   bigint(20) 
2   name                 varchar(191)
3   range                bigint(20)
4   created_at           timestamp
5   updated_at           timestamp
```

**AppServiceProvider**

```
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    $colleges = College::all();
    View::share('colleges', $colleges);
    $departments = Department::with('college')->get();
    View::share('departments', $departments);
    $courses = Course::all();
    View::share('courses', $courses);

}
```

**Blade**

```
@if(!empty($course->courseGroup))
<td>{{$course->courseGroup->name}}</td>
@else
<td>-</td>
@endif
```

I also tried to write it this way:

```
{{$course->courseGroup['name']}}
```

but I still get an empty value.

Please correct me if I did anything wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try $course->courseGroup->name ?

Comment: When I removed @if(!empty($course->courseGroup)) and just leave it {{$course->courseGroup->name}} I get this error Trying to get property 'name' of non-object. and if I tried to use {{$course->courseGroup['name']}} I get empty value.

Comment: Can you debug whats in $course->courseGroup ?

Comment: What is `$course`? Where is it defined?

Comment: $course is defined in foreach like this @foreach($courses as $course).

Comment: @PeterG. $course->courseGroup when I debugged it I get empty value.